# R write(append=TRUE) overwrites file contents

Tags: r, file-io, append

Here's my R code:

```
out = file('testfile')
write('hello', file=out, append=T)
write('world', file=out, append=T)
close(out)
```

When I run this (using R 3.1.0), testfile then contains:

```
world
```

I expected:

```
hello
world
```

The same behavior happens if I use `cat()` instead of `write()`.  Why?  How can I append to files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must open the file for writing:

```
out = file('testfile', 'w')
...
```

When R opens (or does not open) connections automatically is a bit complicated, but it's explained in the help (`?file`).

If you do not pass `'w'`, each `write` call opens and closes the file, and I guess this causes the strange behaviour you observe.

If you want to open an existing file for appending, use

```
out = file('testfile', 'a')
```

Comment: That is well and truly amazing.  First that file(name) doesn't open the file, but moreover append=T doesn't do what it says (that's an outright bug I'd say, curious if you agree).

Comment: It seems to me that file(...) opens the file for *reading* and that, when you write to a file already open for reading, R tries to work around the problem and the workaround gives strange results. `append=TRUE` does what it is supposed to do if you do not previously open the file with `file`, but rather simply write `write("Hello", "filename", append=TRUE)`.

Comment: Right, I understand.  Given this workaround, do you agree that it would be preferable to make it so that write(append=T) with a non-open file connection will open the file for appending, rather than overwrite it?  This seems like it might be worth a patch to R.

Answer (score 4):

The clue comes in the help page for `cat` (which `write` is a wrapper for):

> `append` logical. Only used if the argument file is the name of file
>   (and not a connection or "|cmd"). If TRUE output will be appended to
>   file; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents of file.

When using connections you should set the connection to be opened for appending, eg:

```
file('testfile', open="a")
```